# How to compute contrats between levels of a parameter in bayesian mixed-effects models and produce bayes factors in R?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-models, compare-contrast

I would like to compute contrats between different levels of a parameter from my bayesian mixed-effects models in R, and produce bayes factors. My outcome (Jud) is binary (1=Yes/In synch, 0=No/Out of synch) and the parameter SOAsF is a factor with 6 levels (0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500).

Following different tutorials/functions [[#1]](https://easystats.github.io/bayestestR/articles/bayes_factors.html#appendices),[[#2]](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/parameter-contrasts-in-bayesian-linear-regression-model-using-brms/6348/6) and [[#3]](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/brms/versions/2.12.0/topics/hypothesis.brmsfit), here is my code with the 3 different manners:

```
 library(emmeans)
    library(brms)
    library(modelbased)

    brm_acc_1<-brm(Jud ~ SOAsF +(1|pxID),data =dat_long, family=bernoulli("logit"), prior = set_prior('normal(0,10)'), iter = 2000, chains=4,  save_all_pars = TRUE)
    summary(brm_acc_1)
    brms::conditional_effects(brm_acc_1)

    ####1           
    groups <- emmeans(brm_acc_1, ~ SOAsF)
    group_diff <- pairs(groups)
    (groups_all <- rbind(groups, group_diff))        
    bayesfactor_parameters(groups_all, prior = brm_acc_1, direction = "two-sided", effects = c("fixed", "random", "all"))

    ####2   
    ppc <- pp_check(brm_acc_1, type = "stat_grouped", group = "SOAsF")
    #contrast 200 - 300
    contrast_300_200 <- ppc$data$value[ppc$data$group == "200"] - ppc$data$value[ppc$data$group == "300"]
    quantile(contrast_300_200*100, probs = c(.5, .025, .975))

    ####3
    h_1 <- hypothesis(brm_acc_1, "SOAsF200 < SOAsF300")
    print(h1, digits = 4)
    h2 <- hypothesis(brm_acc_1, "SOAsF200 > SOAsF300")
    print(h2, digits = 4)
```

Outcome:

[image]

```
 ####1
# Bayes Factor (Savage-Dickey density ratio)

    Parameter    |       BF
    -----------------------
    0, .         | 8.08e-03
    100, .       |     0.61
    200, .       | 7.29e+03
    300, .       |    67.77
    400, .       |    21.81
    500, .       |     0.28
    ., 0 - 100   |     2.75
    ., 0 - 200   | 1.90e+05
    ., 0 - 300   |   410.42
    ., 0 - 400   |   570.11
    ., 0 - 500   |     1.03
    ., 100 - 200 |      0.5
    ., 100 - 300 |     0.05
    ., 100 - 400 |     0.02
    ., 100 - 500 | 7.13e-03
    ., 200 - 300 |     0.01
    ., 200 - 400 |     0.01
    ., 200 - 500 |     1.11
    ., 300 - 400 | 7.21e-03
    ., 300 - 500 |      0.1
    ., 400 - 500 |     0.04

    * Evidence Against The Null: [0]

  ####2
   50%      2.5%     97.5% 
 1.988631 -3.707585  7.680694 

  ####3

Hypothesis Tests for class b:
                Hypothesis Estimate Est.Error CI.Lower CI.Upper
1 (SOAsF200)-(SOAsF... < 0   0.0881    0.0903  -0.0612   0.2372
  Evid.Ratio Post.Prob Star
1     0.1919     0.161     
---
'CI': 90%-CI for one-sided and 95%-CI for two-sided hypotheses.
'*': For one-sided hypotheses, the posterior probability exceeds 95%;
for two-sided hypotheses, the value tested against lies outside the 95%-CI.
Posterior probabilities of point hypotheses assume equal prior probabilities.

Hypothesis Tests for class b:
                Hypothesis Estimate Est.Error CI.Lower CI.Upper
1 (SOAsF200)-(SOAsF... > 0   0.0881    0.0903  -0.0612   0.2372
  Evid.Ratio Post.Prob Star
1     5.2112     0.839     
---
'CI': 90%-CI for one-sided and 95%-CI for two-sided hypotheses.
'*': For one-sided hypotheses, the posterior probability exceeds 95%;
for two-sided hypotheses, the value tested against lies outside the 95%-CI.
Posterior probabilities of point hypotheses assume equal prior probabilities.
```

So taking the example of the contrasts 200 vs 300. Are sounds presented at SOA 200 equally judged as in synch (yes) compared to sounds presented at SOA 300?

Manner #1 seems to provide evidence toward the null hypothesis SOA 200 - SOA 300 = 0 with BF = 0.01; so they seem equally jusged as in synch?

Manner #2 seems to provide little evidence toward the null hypothesis SOA 200 = SOA 300 with the evidence being 1.988631% 95%CI [-3.707585, 7.680694].

Manner #3 seems to provide evidence toward the alternative hypothesis SOA 200 > SOA 300 OR SOA 200 - SOA 300 < 0 with BF = 5.2112.

Do I find differences because #1 is two-sided while #3 is one-sided?

However, I did not manage to run #1 one-sided (with direction = "left" or "right")

```
bayesfactor_parameters(groups_all, prior = brm_acc_1, direction = ">",  effects = c("fixed", "random", "all") )
Computation of Bayes factors: sampling priors, please wait...
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "ind", value = 8L) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Or #3 two-sided ( hypothesis(brm_acc_1, " SOAsF200 - SOAsF300 = 0 ") )

```
Hypothesis Tests for class b:
               Hypothesis Estimate Est.Error CI.Lower CI.Upper
1 (SOAsF200-SOAsF300) = 0   0.0881    0.0903  -0.0914   0.2682
  Evid.Ratio Post.Prob Star
1         NA        NA     
---
'CI': 90%-CI for one-sided and 95%-CI for two-sided hypotheses.
'*': For one-sided hypotheses, the posterior probability exceeds 95%;
for two-sided hypotheses, the value tested against lies outside the 95%-CI.
Posterior probabilities of point hypotheses assume equal prior probabilities.
```

I am stuck, any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer in why you have a difference between #1 and #3. In #1 it calculate a Bayes factor meaning that the function give you the evidence of H1 divided by the evidence of H0. In #3 it give you the evidence of your hypothesis >0 (H1) but it is not a bayes factor, if you want to factorize you should compute the evidence for hypothesis =0 (H0) and to do a factor of H1/H0 (for BF10).

Cheers.